# Add subdomain on Apache2

Tags: dns, apache2, virtualhost

I want to add a subdomain `api.example.com` on Apache2.
Here is my configuration file for the domain.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName api.winity.pw
    ServerAdmin webmaster@winity.pw
    DocumentRoot /var/www/api

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I tried to access it without working, here is my DNS configuration on CloudFlare [image: 1]

When I try to access it, I find myself in the `/var/www/public` directory and not `/var/www/api`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First when asking here.

1. Google the question
2. Search on StackOverflow
3. Make a relevant title for you `Create subdomain in Apache2`
4. Specify your operating system not your type of server**

---

Use **443** port over **SSL** by changing `<VirtualHost *:80>` to `<VirtualHost *:443>`.

If you receive an **`HTTP 525 - SSL Handshake failed`** error from **CloudFlare**, use **Flexible SSL** option.
This append when you use **Full SSL** and you don't have a valid SSL certificat on your server.

[image: 1]

For fix this issue, change the SSL option to **Flexible**.